# How to get the ArcBees sample GWTP-Crawler running on AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

I tried to run the GWTP crawler running on google appengine.

https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Crawler-Support

https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples/tree/master/gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-crawler-service

Since the docu is very short I could not get it running.

I can deploy my gwtp-cralwer but I get the following error when I try to crawl an application.

I tried an url like this:

```
http://testcrawler.appspot.com/?key=123456&url=http://google.com
```

and got the following error

```
80.171.208.157 - - [11/Feb/2014:08:59:18 -0800] "GET /?key=123456&url=http://google.com HTTP/1.1" 200 41 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36" "testcrawler.appspot.com" ms=7082 cpu_ms=2209 cpm_usd=0.000005 pending_ms=3689 app_engine_release=1.9.0 instance=00c61b117ca91589d80617271db80bb7cba3a3
W 2014-02-11 08:59:18.623
Error for /
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FIREFOX_17
    at com.gwtplatform.crawlerservice.server.guice.CrawlServiceModule.getWebClient(CrawlServiceModule.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    at com.gwtplatform.crawlerservice.server.CrawlServiceServlet.renderPage(CrawlServiceServlet.java:226)
    at com.gwtplatform.crawlerservice.server.CrawlServiceServlet.renderResponse(CrawlServiceServlet.java:161)
    at com.gwtplatform.crawlerservice.server.CrawlServiceServlet.doGet(CrawlServiceServlet.java:106)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

How do I have to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise this in [ArcBees GWTP-Samples Issues](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples/issues).  There is insufficient information in your question for programmers on the Internet to reproduce the problem.  If nobody else will help you, concentrate your search on where the text FIREFOX_17 is coming from - it should most likely be a value, not a field name.